# curl POST request to localhost says failed to connect to localhost where localhost is up

Tags: php, curl

I have a node server running on localhost:3000 and I am using cURL in php to send a POST request to the localhost. I get error: (7)

> Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000: Connection refused

```
$url = 'http://localhost:3000';
$data = array('url'=>$_POST['url']);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
var_dump( $response );
echo curl_getinfo($curl) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($curl) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($curl) . '<br/>';
curl_close( $curl );`
```

> Error:(7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000: Connection refused

I did try with `127.0.0.1` and it didn't work. I am sure that the server is listening on the port. I did node app.js and as expected it said:

> Example app listening on port 3000!

Then I did `curl -d "url=google.com" -X POST localhost:3000` from another terminal and it worked completely fine. 
Don't know why it would't work with php.

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Avoid using localhost, test with 127.0.0.1 in `$url`. Then, are you sure that the port is opened and an application is listen this port? Check your service on port 3000 via some tools to provide us a more complete message. If this is a nodejs service, check nodejs log and edit your post with these log.

Comment: I did try with 127.0.0.1 and it didn't work. I am sure that the server is listening on the port. I did `node app.js` and it said "Example app listening on port 3000!" as expected. Then I did `curl -d "url=http://www.google.com" -X POST http://localhost:3000' from another terminal and it worked completely fine. Don't know why it would't work with php.